# How to hide a div after clicking javascript:history.go in with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form and after submiting it I have a review page. If user wants to edit something in the form I use

```
<A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)">Edit</A>
```

By this way I don't have to repopulate datas from somewhere. It basically goes backward.
The problem is when I turn back to page, If I have form validation errors from previous page, It still remains there. 
Therefore, what I want to do is to hide the div id/class when I click Edit button. 
Form validation error are in a div so probably solution with hiding it will be better.

Thanks

Comment: Still there is no solution I think?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourDivId").hide();
});
```

Comment: But I have just want it to be when I click edit. Not all time. I want form validation in my page but I don't want only someone clicks edit. Because it shows old validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

call a javascript function on EDIT button instead of calling history.go(-1), and inside that javascript function first toggle the divs that you want to hide, and then do history.back

Comment: But this method will refresh the page isn't it? Now it doesn't refresh. It just goes to back page like clicking back on browser.

Comment: one thing you can do is on submit, make an ajax call for the review page, instead of directly changing the url, and then on confirm you can post the content, or what you can do it, you have the data on the confirm page, you can use that data to repopulate the form.

Comment: SNaRe, exactly, it goes back like clicking back on the browser, and you're asking how to make it not like clicking back on the browser...

Comment: What I want is when I click edit, it will go back to page without 'refresh'( So input fields will be filled, and It will hide a specific DIV. So It will not refresh the page this is the most important part but hide a div after he goes back to the page.

Comment: if you want to do it urgently, then instead of using the history, repopulate the content of the form on click on the edit button, mean while for future search for a approach to set some global parameter while doing history.go(-1)

Comment: It's called "history" for a reason. Leave re-writing history to politicians. Users might want history to remain as they remembered it.

Comment: But the problem is it is useless history anymore. Because since it is a form validation error, he pass to review page it is already validated so there is no more from validation error. That's why I want to hide it. I know not a big problem but I thought jquery/javascript can do it